# list и Массивы в python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня такое задание ...Создать класс-сборщик. В нем реализовать методы сложения (k число, что добавляют) отнимания, умножения.В главном методе создать массив с м объектов и использовать к нему все написанные методы... 
В питоне, ест списки, а массивы можно создать только с помощью  доп библиотеки?
Вопрос вот в чем, можно ли сделать это задание используя лист и как примерно это будет выглядеть? Если нет то как с массивом?

```
k = input('Ваше число k: ')
nams = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
k*x for x in nams:
print(nams)
```

Comment: А в чем вы видите разницу между списком и массивом?

Comment: list в питоне реализован именно как обычный массив

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Не вижу, просто знаю, что есть библиотека nampy и модуль array вот и думаю, к чему они тогда?

Comment: @kkkkkkkk для вашей задачи — ни к чему

Comment: @kkkkkkkk А если нет разницы - зачем придумывать сложности?

Comment: @andreymal А, что б сделать сделать добавление нужного числа ко всем элементам в листе нужно реализововать через фор?

Comment: @kkkkkkkk ну да, это самый очевидный и простой вариант, IMHO

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Просто у меня не работает это, мб я не так это делаю но не работает. Посмотрите плиз в шапке, я закину

Comment: @kkkkkkkk учебник почитайте, строчка `k*x for x in nams:` бессмысленна

Comment: @andreymal тут читал 
https://pep8.ru/doc/tutorial-2.6/6.html

Comment: @kkkkkkkk и той строчки, которую вы написали, там нет, читайте ещё раз

Comment: @andreymal она там так выглядит >>> vec = [2, 4, 6]
>>> [3*x for x in vec] # умножить каждое число в списке vec на три
[6, 12, 18]

Comment: @kkkkkkkk вот так и пишите

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
k = int(input('Ваше число k: '))
nams = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
a = [k*x for x in nams]
print(a)
```

Ну вот так заработает вроде