# Функция возвращает None

Tags: python

```
def pluss():
    a = [k * x for x in nams]
    print(a)

print(pluss())
```

Там программа выводит числа, а на новой строке None как убрать?

Comment: Оператор return - очень полезная штука...

Comment: связанный вопрос [Разница между print и return при возврате значения из функции](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/618734/23044)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def pluss():
    a = [k * x for x in nams]
    return a

print(pluss())
```

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Comment: @kkkkkkkk нужно помогать)

Answer (score 0):

Итого здравствуйте.
Вы взяли ответ из предыдущего поста и тупо сделали функцию не подумав что такое k что такое nams. Может быть Вы читатель подумал что там глобальная переменная. По где об этом говорится??

```
k=100
nams=[10,15]

def pluss():
    global k
    global nams
    a = [k * x for x in nams]
    return(a)

print(pluss())
```

А может так

```
def pluss(k,nams):
    a = [k * x for x in nams]
    return(a)

k=100
nams=[10,15]
print(pluss(k,nams))
```

Comment: Какой еще предыдущий пост? К кому обращен этот ответ? Что вы вообще хотели этим сказать?

Comment: А зачем скобки в `return(a)` ?

Comment: Это было раньше Вашего вопроса. 
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/756863/list-%D0%B8-%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8B-%D0%B2-python3

По поводу скобок. Скобки автоматом ставлю, однако тут написано более подробно и не вижу смысла перепечатывать
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978567/should-a-return-statement-have-parentheses

Comment: Зачем явно указывать что это глобальные переменные? Это очевидно. В функции нет к примеру `nonlocal` что говорит о том что переменные из уровня выше, если переменные не объявлены внутри функции, очевидно что они глобальные.